# Adding collapsible sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have created my website using Bootstrap. I want to add a facebook-like collapsible sidebar. I have tried to divide my website into two columns. One for the sidebar and other for the whole website using `col-md-2` and `col-md-10` but the problem that was occurring was the site was being overflown towards the right side. This is what I did:

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-2">...Sidebar...</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">...Rest of the website...</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

But the site was overflowing towards the right side. I tried that with many other `col-*` but to no avail. I also added `.clearfix` class to the body but still could not fix the overflowing issue.

**Q1. How can I fix the overflowing issue?**

Secondly, I want to make the sidebar collapsible. I thought I would do that by hiding the `col-md-2` and changing the class of the website holder div to `col-md-12` and reversing the thing when the user un-collapses the sidebar but the problem I know that would be occurring is that I would not be having a smooth sliding effect.

**Q2. How could I make a collapsible siderbar with a smooth slide effect?**

[Demo of what's happening.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fUCt8/show/)

Answer (score 1):

Q1:  Have you tried adding a row after the container?

```
<div class="contianer">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">...Sidebar...</div>
      <div class="col-md-10">...Content...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Q2:  You can create you sider bar off the top of the screen and animate it in using jquery to slide it down to where you want it when the menu button is clicked.

Comment: Adding the row didn't fixed the problem. And I want the sidebar to be at the left, facebook-like. :)

Comment: Oh ok i get it now its because you are using a container inside of a container.  You want to get rid of the second container. When that is used it is creating another container with the width of 1170px and pushing the content off the right of the page. You can just create rows and cols inside of a col, no container needed